# Filter excel data by most recent date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of IDs, dates and scores and I need to get the score corresponding to the latest date. The data looks like this:

```
ID  |   Date      |  Score
___________________________
123 |  03/15/2016 |  10
123 |  08/10/2016 |  4
456 |  09/01/2016 |  7
456 |  02/02/2016 |  10
678 |  07/01/2016 |  2
987 |  04/18/2016 |  9
987 |  03/02/2016 |  4
```

I want to pull the score for the most recent date, and only have one line per ID. Ideally, the finished table would look like this.

```
ID  |   Date      |  Score
___________________________
123 | 08/10/2016  |  4
456 | 09/01/2016  |  7
678 | 07/01/2016  |  2
987 | 04/18/2016  |  9
```

I have tried to filter and sort this, but I have not been able to. If anyone has any ideas, or a snippet of VBA that would accomplish this, that would be awesome.

Comment: Sort on column B descending then use remove duplicates on Column A.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I think I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by date and filter the ID on your choice.